# Setting my lib for LD_PRELOAD makes some processes produce loader errors

Tags: c++, c, linux, linker, dlsym

I get the following error when I try to run a script I have only execution access for:

`uname: symbol lookup error: /home/dumindara/random/sotest/a.out: undefined symbol: dlsym`

This is after I have set `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable to `/home/dumindara/random/sotest/a.out`.

`a.out` has a test `malloc` function, and calls `dlsym` internally.

I don't get this problem when running `ls`. Most processes do give this error. Why does this happen and what can I do to make it work?

Comment: It's generally a good idea to set LD_PRELOAD only for a.out, rather than modifying the shell environment.  In most UNIX shells you can type: `LD_PRELOAD=xyz ./a.out`.  Otherwise, try `( LD_PRELOAD=xyz; ./a.out )`.

Comment: @Tony: I think that a.out is a shared object in this case, despite its ill-chosen name. The OP is apparently trying to override `malloc()` with their own version and then pass-through to the real malloc.

Comment: @tkhala: ah, good catch... would be more like `LD_PRELOAD=\`pwd\`/a.out program_to_test` then....

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I assume that your a.out file is a shared object and not a executable and move on...

`dlsym()` is a function from the libdl library, which usually resides in the libdl.so.2 shared object on modern Linux systems.

I'll hazzard a guess that your a.out shared object is not linked to libdl. That means that when you preload in a simple binary like uname that does not pull in a lot of other libraries, libdl.so.2 may not be pulled in and you get an undefined symbol error.

If, on the other hand, you preload it to a binary that is linked to and finally pulls in libdl.so.2, your shared object works fine.

I'd check with `ldd` if your own shared object is linked against libdl as it should, and also what libraries are directly or indirectly pulled in when `uname` and `ls` run.

EDIT:

I just confirmed this. The way to fix this error is to link your shared object against libdl. Adding `-ldl` to its LDFLAGS should do the trick.

Comment: Note that -ldl may need to be before the other .o files, e.g. "gcc -ldl -shared foo.o bar.o -o baz.so".

Comment: As happened to be mentioned in answer below, `-ldl` actually should go at the end of `gcc` line if linking and compilation is done together. I've read explanation that `gcc` builds list of symbols from files and then searches for them in libraries mentioned after their names for some reason.

Answer (score 38):

I am unable to comment to the accepted answer, however it is worth to mention here that one can encounter issue of not having libdl.so.2 linked properly when `-ldl` is used in front of compile command (assuming that linking and compilation is executed by the same command; this is possible since LD_PRELOAD libs are usually based on one source file).

So call gcc with `-ldl` at the end:

`gcc -shared -fPIC fakeuname.c -o libfakeuname.so -ldl`

In my case, having `-ldl` at front resulted in error same as in question:

`uname: symbol lookup error: ./libfakehostname.so: undefined symbol: dlsym`

Comment: yes thumbs up!!! thkala answer still gave me error, but your "-ldl" at the end solved everything.