# Wrapping malloc using the LD_PRELOAD trick

Tags: c, glibc, libc

My goal is to wrap `malloc()` with my own implementation and then inject that implementation into executables using `LD_PRELOAD` trick for educational purposes.

I've made two files, `test.c` for testing the injection and `wrapper.c` which wraps `malloc()` and is compiled as a shared library.

What seems to be happening is `dlsym()` is calling `malloc()` under the hood, causing the infinite recursion until the stack runs out, at which point a segfault occurs.

I've had to use `write()` instead of `fprintf()` for the same reason, but I can't figure out the workaround for `dlsym()`.

This approach seems to be inline with other [implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083337/overriding-malloc-using-the-ld-preload-mechanism), so I'm a confused why this isn't working for me.

```c
// test.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char* string = "test start\n";
    write(2, string, strlen(string));

    (void)malloc(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Built with:

```
gcc -o test test.c
```

```c
// wrapper.c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void* (*real_malloc)(size_t size) = NULL;

void* malloc(size_t size)
{
    const char* string = "malloc()\n";
    write(2, string, strlen(string));
    
    if (real_malloc == NULL) {
        real_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Built with:

```
gcc -c -fPIC -o wrapper.o wrapper.c
gcc -shared -o wrapper.so wrapper.o
```

Ran with:

```
LD_PRELOAD=wrapper.so ./test
```

Returns:

```
test start
malloc()
...
malloc()
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

EDIT:

Using the [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083337/overriding-malloc-using-the-ld-preload-mechanism/56630217#56630217) revealed that I wasn't linking the `wrapper` correctly. I was still getting getting:

```
./test: symbol lookup error: wrapper.so: undefined symbol: dlsym
```

Adding `-ldl` solved the problem:

```
gcc -shared -o wrapper.so wrapper.o -ldl
```

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385155/setting-my-lib-for-ld-preload-makes-some-processes-produce-loader-errors).

Comment: For starters your `malloc` does not return a value.

Comment: @EugeneSh. fixed.

Comment: Quite a few of the answers in the question you linked to explain how to work around this issue, for example : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56630217/742314

Comment: Your malloc does not allocate memory..

Comment: @idz That answer does seem like it would work, thank you.